# Formatting string lines in groovy

Tags: groovy, sh, string-formatting

Newbie to groovy; sorry if i am asking a stupid question...

As a result of the command:

`String Index = sh(script: "ls", returnStdout:true).trim()`

Output:

`book.txt book1.txt book2.txt`

in one liner.

The command:

`sh "ls"`

Output:

`book.txt`

`book1.txt`

`book2.txt`

Why is this happening in one liner and how can I format it?

Comment: What do you mean by "format" it?  I guess you want to use `ls -1` in your first example, if you are after "file per line".  Yet be aware, that there are more elegant ways with groovy to list all files in a directory.

Comment: No, i need the output book.txt book1.txt book 2.txt in multiline